# CSS Text Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css

as you can see in the index page of my blog http://www.lowcoupling.com, each post has a box on the left in which the number of comments is depicted. I'd like to have this text aligned vertically. The problem is the height of the row depends on the width of the browser and on the number of characters in the post. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: please produce some code or jsfiddle

Comment: DO you have access to edit the code of said blog? You need to be a little more specific! But yes it is possible if you can fully edit the page source.

Comment: sorry, I do have access to the whole css

Comment: I don't understand what you want...

Comment: create a fiddle please.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.commentBox {
    margin-top: 10px;
}`  Due to the amount of lines in your heading varying this will be difficult to get it exactly center but you can adjust the height top something of your liking

Comment: I mean the "0 Comments" text to be centered (vertically) with respect to the text on the right side

Answer (score 0):

as you are not giving any code or jsfiddle,question is unclear..there are many solutions which may work...try `text-align:center` or `vertical-align:middle` for your texts inside comment box's div... or `margin-top:10px` for comment box

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this kind of trick for a little while now, let me know how it works for you

```
.container .row .col-lg-10 > .row {
    display: table;
}

.container .row .col-lg-10 > .row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the technical answer for that — but in short, it won't work if the elements are floated. It has to do with the default display properties associated with table elements.